# Disable colorpicker for <input type="color"> in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, `<input type="color">` creates an input with a big bar of color inside it and by default, opens a colorpicker (looks like it's OS dependent, mine has a Windows skin). I'm using a custom colorpicker globally that hooks into `type="color"` which looks like this in most browsers:

[image: text input with colored borders]

But in Chrome it looks like this:

[image: solid colored bar with padding and a colored border]

If you've never seen it before, a bare-bones one looks like this (Windows 7 64bit Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m):

[image]

The custom colorpicker overrides the default one just fine, but the problem is the way it's displayed in Chrome. Another problem is that I can't seem to clear the value (have tried js), the default value is always `#000000` and can't be set to an empty one.

It may or may not be true that if I don't want this behavior I shouldn't use `type="color"`, but sometimes I find Chrome's UI a little too aggressive. Changing all the input `type`s is not something I look forward to, and I'm not positive what else the app is doing with them so I could end up breaking something else. I've had similar issues with date pickers.

Is there any way to change this behavior in Chrome so I can have a normal text-like field? JavaScript/jQuery is an option, but if it can be done with CSS `-webkit` rules somehow that would be great.

Comment: never knew that there's something like `type="color"` :D Edit: btw I just tried but am not able to get it work, which version are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m: http://jsfiddle.net/sfBK8/

Comment: I guess there's no way where you can treat this as a text box unless and until the user browser is old like mine(But as a developer I don't upgrade to latest)..

Comment: Why do you want to change it?  There are some things that just should not be toyed with, such as form elements.  Opera also supports the new input types (and has for a long time), but it defaults to black.

Comment: @cimmanon: We don't have any Opera users but you're right - the behavior is similar in Opera. I might just have to bite the bullet and change all the input types. As far as *why* I want to change it: so the user can opt to leave the field blank - this is the backend of a CMS and we want the user to be able to do things like paste color codes (which Opera allows, Chrome does not seem to), or leave it blank to use default values. This was built a long time ago before Chrome was as widely used as it is now.

Comment: Compare to `type="date"` which, while it has datepickers validation and formatting, at least allows empty values. It may very well be the correct answer to say this cannot be done, just get used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use type=color in this case. According to the standard, input[type=color] can't have an empty value.

> [If the value of the element is a valid simple color, then set it to the value of the element converted to ASCII lowercase; otherwise, set it to the string "#000000".](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#color-state-%28type=color%29)

Comment: Here, I filed a bug (feature request) for the standard, citing this question https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21996

Answer (score 2):

For the display issues, try overriding the default User Agent styles: http://jsfiddle.net/ngBpA/

```
input[type="color"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    display: none;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
    display: none;
}​
```

I'm assuming your plugin automatically resizes the box.

User Agent Stylesheet: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

Comment: I knew there had to be something with `-webkit` rules, let me give this a go and see how it works out, thanks for the info. The main problem is not being able to clear the value, but this could fix some of the ugliness.

Comment: That did help with the display aspect, but for some reason `::-webkit-color-swatch` wasn't needed and somehow made plugin's colorpicker inputs really wide (which are just `type="text"`, strange). There's still a ton of extra padding I can't remove but it looks better.